# How to add animation to contentContainerStyle?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I'm currently trying to animate a scrollview, so it adjusts to the height of an accordian above it. I'm trying to get the scrollView to offset by using an animation but I keep getting the error Transform with key of "translateY" must be a number: {"translateY":0}. If I wrap it in Animated.View the animation no longer works?

```
  <AnimatedScrollView
      {...props}
      onScroll={Animated.event([
        { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scroll } } },
      ])}
      scrollEventThrottle={16}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        transform: [
          {
            translateY: this.state.contentOffset,
          },
        ],
      }}
    >
```

Comment: Hi, did you managed to find out how it works? I'm having a similar problem too

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue that I resolved by not using `contentContainerStyle` at all. I added an `Animated.View` between the `Animated.ScrollView` and my original scrollview children, then added my animated styles to *that*:

```
<Animated.ScrollView>
    <Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>
        {/* original scrollview children */}
    </Animated.View>
</Animated.ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. I'm still wondering why contentContainerStyle is unable to use an animated value though. Do you mind explaining why?

Comment: @ChanJingHong My assumption is that internally, ScrollView is putting its children inside a View with `style` set to the value of its own `contentContainerStyle` prop. Maybe it should be reported as a bug, since it seems like the fix would simply be to use an Animated.View instead.

Comment: I see, yeah that makes sense to me. Thanks!